# saving custom object Type variable using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

i have a spring boot and hibernate based project that contains a simple schedule(pojo) class and an entity class to save in mysql using hibernate.

Now i want to create a field in tutorAvailableSchedules entity which is an array of schedule type .
when i try the below code it gives me the error.

availableSchedule.class ->pojo

```
package fG.Model;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class availablitySchedule {
    String startTime;
    String endTime;
    String days[];
}
```

TutorAvailablitySchedules.class ->Entity

```
package fG.Entity;
import fG.Model.availablitySchedule;

@Entity
public class TutorAvailablitySchedules {

    @Id
    Integer tid;
    String fullName;
    availablitySchedule[] availableSchedules;
    String currentSchedule;
    String availablityStatus;
}
```

error  i get:

```
 Could not determine type for: fG.Model.availablitySchedule, at table: tutor_availablity_schedules, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(available_schedules)]
```

Comment: How do you want to store an instance of `availablitySchedule` in the database? Please respect Java naming conventions, e.g. classes start witch capital letter and package names contain only small letters and `.`.

Comment: @MichaelKreutz i will make sure of it next time

Comment: And how do you think about my question "How do you want to store an instance of availablitySchedule in the database?" ?

Comment: @MichaelKreutz using mapping annotations?

Comment: @MichaelKreutz if you know then solution please help me with it

Answer (score 0):

I will sketch you a possible solution. It may need some refinement, depending on how you want to model the relationship of your entities.

1. You could annotate class `AvailablitySchedule` as `@Entity` such that it reflects a table. As a consequence you will have to think about an id.
2. Refactor `AvailablitySchedule[] availableSchedules` in class `TutorAvailablitySchedules` to `List<AvailablitySchedule> availableSchedules`
3. Define a `@OneToMany` relationship between `TutorAvailablitySchedules` and `AvailablitySchedule` by annotating field `List<AvailablitySchedule> availableSchedules` in `TutorAvailablitySchedules` with `@OneToMany`
4. Change  `String[] days;` to `List<String> days;` in class `AvailablitySchedule`
5. Annotate `List<String> days;` with e.g. `@ElementCollection`.
6. Look at the tables that are created and think about if this is the structure you want to have.